# how to print query in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.2

Actually,

I have written this code in **AppController.php** in **CakePHP 2.2.2**

```
class AppModel extends Model
{
  function getLastQuery()
  {
      $dbo = $this->getDatasource();
      $logs = $dbo->getLog();
      $lastLog = end($logs['log']);
      return $lastLog['query'];
  }
}
```

I tried following code to print output query

```
echo $this->AssetModel->getLastQuery(); 
$this->render('sql');
```

Is any body know to the point solution for that....?

Answer (score 1):

I use this in **CakePHP 2.6.11** to print Queries from Model in browser

```
debug($this->YOURMODEL->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false)); exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the below line to put into your layout file

```
<?php  echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```

this will print all running query running in current action.

You can also use [cakephp debugkit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) plugin.